# onload event not working. [Javascript]

Tags: javascript

I have the onclick event: `onclick="javascript:_stats_content('my_bets');"` which works fine.

This loads new content into a div.

However I want to set a default piece of content to load when the page loads. I have attempted to do this with the code below, but it is not working:

```
<body onload="myFunction()">

<script>
function myFunction() {
_stats_content('my_bets'); // have also tried with 'javascript:' infront
}
</script>
```

Can anyone provide any solutions?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Upon reading comments, I have added `type="text/javascript"`.

I also replaced with an alert() and it fails to show. I should note that I am using AngularJS to display the page so this might interfere. However the first onclick example works fine on the page, so I don't understand how onload would be any different.

EDIT2: This is an extract of code from the top of the page:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="content/ext/msgbox/Scripts/jquery.msgBox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/ext/msgbox/Styles/msgBoxLight.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="content/ext/qtip/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/ext/qtip/jquery.qtip.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/colors.js"></script>   
<?php include './js/includer.php'; ?>
</head>

<body onload="myFunction()">
```

I have replaced with an alert to make it easier to troubleshoot, although the alert is still not showing. I think it's just an AngularJS related issue, guess I'll just have to figure this out.

Comment: How is it not working? Is it not firing?

Comment: could it be that you are also using jQuery or anthing similar?

Comment: It probably works (as a function is being called), I'm thinking it's that `_stats_content()` is undefined and it's showing that in the console.

Comment: Press F12 and look in the error console

Comment: Can you provide any error? If you put an alert() in the myFunction, does it display? Also, you should have type="text/javascript" in your script tag.

Comment: If you keep the script at the bottom of the page, before the </body> tag, you do not need to hook into the body onload event. Script gets executed when the DOM is done parsing the HTML in the body. Otherwise, put the script in the head, because the moment onload="myFunction" is encountered, myFunction should exist. Since the script tags are after the <body> tag, myFunction does not exist before it's being referenced.

Comment: @dman2306 you don't have to add type="text/javascript"

Comment: @BGerrissen I've updated my question with an extract of code, could you explain with an answer the structure you recommend.

Comment: where are you closing your <head> tag? and why do you have two body tags?

Comment: @MuppetGrinder sorry removed the first one. Do I need to have head tags?

Comment: erm...yeah...is that the actual top of your document? O_o

Comment: @mahatmanich It depends, in HTML4, the type attribute is required see http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#adef-type-SCRIPT in HTML5 it is not. It's not the cause of his problem, merely mentioning it should be done to be standards compliant :)

Comment: Hmm, do any of the scripts included assign a function to body.onload (body.onload = function(){...})? That would basically override your inline onload assignment before it's fired. Also check for console errors please.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I wasn't able to get this exact method to work, the reason for which I still have no idea. I imagine it's AngularJS interfering.

I used:

```
<img src="87.jpg" onload="javascript:_stats_content('my_bets');" width="0" height="0">
```

Just before the `</body>` tag and that worked.